# Cassandra production Monitoring

Tags: cassandra, datastax, ganglia

I am new to Cassandra and trying to setup monitoring to Cassandra production cluster. 
Apart from monitoring using nodetool commands in crontab what else is recommended?
is it a general practice to use ganglia for monitoring?
can you direct me to a good resource on setting up monitoring in production. 
we are using apache cassandra so opscenter was not very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free version of OpsCenter works with OSS Cassandra and most monitoring capabilities are available. You do miss a good amount of cluster management capabilities if you don't have DSE:

http://www.datastax.com/what-we-offer/products-services/datastax-opscenter/compare